# Editing the woocommerce checkout page "order notes"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I want to change the woocommerce checkout page's 'order notes' text field to 'special notes'. But I couldn't find the exact location of this file. Where I can find this file in my localhost folder?

Here is the screenshot of the page:

[image: Here is the screenshot of the page]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In this situation direct don't try to edit in plugin files. instead of that try to search for hook.**

**Here is the code you can add it in function file. it will change text and place holder also**

```
function md_custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) 
{
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Special notes';
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Add your special note';

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'md_custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );
```

Comment: yeah that's grate, Always do changes in child theme.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you need to use the **woocommerce_checkout_fields** filter and set **$fields['order']['order_comments']['label']** to the text you want.

Here is the code for it. You should add it to your theme's function.php file or plugin.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'change_order_note_label' );
/**
 * Change Order Notes Label - WooCommerce
 *
 */
function change_order_note_label( $fields ) {

    $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Special notes';
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'theme_override_checkout_notes_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function theme_override_checkout_notes_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Add some order notes or a gift message here.';
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Order notes or  gift message';
     return $fields;
}
```